# Error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Connection Refused - Kube Controller Manager

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubeadm

**LOGS Kube controller Manager**

`Fetching last 1000 lines of logs from kube-controller-manager-raspberrypi pod in kube-system namespace:                                                                                                            I0809 14:22:52.676388       1 serving.go:348] Generated self-signed cert in-memory                                                                                                                                 I0809 14:22:56.015210       1 controllermanager.go:182] Version: v1.26.7                                                                                                                                           I0809 14:22:56.015298       1 controllermanager.go:184] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""                                                                                                     I0809 14:22:56.019346       1 dynamic_cafile_content.go:157] "Starting controller" name="client-ca-bundle::/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt"                                                                             I0809 14:22:56.019348       1 dynamic_cafile_content.go:157] "Starting controller" name="request-header::/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt"                                                                   I0809 14:22:56.024962       1 secure_serving.go:210] Serving securely on 127.0.0.1:10257                                                                                                                           I0809 14:22:56.025012       1 tlsconfig.go:240] "Starting DynamicServingCertificateController"                                                                                                                     I0809 14:22:56.025973       1 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager...                                                                                     E0809 14:22:56.027537       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get "https://192.168.10.252:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-controller-manager?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.10.252:6443: connect: connection refused                                                                                                                    E0809 14:22:59.118080       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get "https://192.168.10.252:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-controller-manager?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.10.252:6443: connect: connection refused                                                                                                                    E0809 14:23:02.225098       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get "https://192.168.10.252:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-controller-manager?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.10.252:6443: connect: connection refused                                                                                                                    E0809 14:23:05.462271       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get "https://192.168.10.252:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-controller-manager?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.10.252:6443: connect: connection r`efused